# Heroku pg:backups:restore from local database

Tags: heroku

Heroku cannot access my google drive file but it is publicly accessible: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B4cYno3qd3jwSnN5V0JtOVZBb1k

Heroku errors:
1, please check the source URL and ensure it is publicly accessible
2, 'id' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

My code:
`heroku pg:backups:restore "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B4cYno3qd3jwSnN5V0JtOVZBb1k" DATABASE_URL --app express-tourism`

You can take a look at [cmd line screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyRY1.jpg)

Comment: Seems like Google Drive redirects you even when you type direct link so it is bad request for Heroku.

Comment: I just do what you do and its work for me

your url also seems ok just make sure its works for anyone with link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use single quotes around backup url. [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import) says:

> If you’re using a Unix-like operating system be sure to use single quotes around the temporary S3 URL, because it might contain ampersands and other characters that will confuse your shell. If you’re running Windows, you must use double-quotes.

I guess it applies as well to Google Drive as to S3.

Comment: I have tried both single and double quotes but had no luck. I created Amazon AWS bucket and it worked with it.

Comment: From the screenshot it almost looks like a bug in Heroku, where it's passing your URL unquoted to another command..
I'd like to think if it's a bug it's been fixed by now, but I guess a workaround might be to try `"'nested quoting'"`..

Answer (score 6):

Got the same issue while using Google drive and then Dropbox. I resolved this by using Dropbox and changing url's 'https' to 'http'.

As per [Heroku's](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import-to-heroku-postgres) docs:

> In order for PG Backups to access and import your dump file you will need to upload it somewhere with an HTTP-accessible URL.

Keep in mind the URL should be a downloadable link as in the mentioned question. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

https://zapier.com/learn/how-to/generate-direct-dropbox-link/

Example `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/49xukdo0vd22pb8/test.file?dl=0`

Remove the URL params (e.g. ?dl=0) and it will work!

Comment: I just want to confirm that this answer is still working. Just saved me a lot of time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had no luck with Google Drive either. Dropbox have worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can try saving backup in S3 and it should work as heroku itself is saving backups on AWS S3.

Comment: try this
`heroku pg:backups:restore " https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4cYno3qd3jwSnN5V0JtOVZBb1k" DATABASE_URL --app express-tourism`

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox works like a charm. Just make sure it's publicly accessible